# Doubly nested parallel for loops and their span

Tags: multithreading, for-loop, parallel-processing, parallel.for

I'm trying to wrap my head around the idea of how parallel-for-loops work, its all rather new to me, and had read this stackoverflow thread, found here [span and parallel loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5918477/span-and-parallel-loop), and found the top answer there really helpful.

What I'm wondering though is if I have a parallel-for-lop that has a parallel-for-lop inside it if they will behave in the following manner (for convenience I'll let n=5 and 'to' means up to and including (<=)):

Here is the code I have in my mind:

```
parallel for j=1 to n{
    parallel for i=1 to j-1{
       Do-something
    }
}
```

And this is the behavior of the threads I'm leaning towards, but would like someone to confirm  if correct:

```
Time           Action
 0       Thread0 creates Thread1
 1       Thread0 creates Thread2, T1 -> T3
 2       T0 -> T4, T1 -> T5
```

Ok here all the threads for the outer look have been created. And now for the inner. Here subXY means thread number y of thread x:

```
time           Action
 3       T0 -> SubT0t0, T1 -> subT1t0, T2-> SubT2t0....  

             //All threads have created a subthread t0 so 5 more threads created.

 4       T0 -> subT1t1, subT0t0 -> subT2t1, T1->subT2t2, subT1t0->subT3t1...

             //All the subthreads created more threads AND the 'Older' threads 
             //created subthreads under other 'Older' threads. 11 more created.

 5       T0 -> subT5t2, subT0t0 -> subT5t3, T1 -> subT5t4, subT5t5

             //All threads have been created.
 6       Execute command Do-something
```

I know this might not be the best description of what I'm thinking, but its the best I can come up with.

Is this correct? Or would a outer loop thread only make a thread connected to him self? For example T1 would only make subT1XX threads?

Also would the threads that do nothing at time 5 execute their commands during that time?

It would help me immensely if someone could help me.

Comment: Did you have to complicate matters my using the j index as the termination limit of the inside loop?  As if this kind of construct is not difficult enough as it is.. :)

Comment: It's a thread/task storm. Time is broken here!

Comment: I'm sorry Martin, not sure what you mean by broken time?

Comment: It's just me  - don't worry about it.  Did you mean to use j as the termination condititn for your inner loop?

Comment: Ah, ok :). Yes, the j was deliberate

Comment: We are talking .NET's parallel for loops here right?  If so, please tag the question with an appropriate platform, like C# or .NET.

Comment: No its not tied to any special language/framework. This is just pure theoretical, and actually comes from the book "Introduction to Algorithms" 3rd editon

Comment: I'll add that the span of these nested loops is O(nlgn) as far as I can see, and that what I was proposing in the question does not happen.

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify how your parallel for is implemented. So let's
assume parallel for is implemented along the lines of this recursive
`pf` function:

```
pf(f, lo, hi):
    n = hi - lo + 1
    if n == 1:
        f(lo)
    else:
        m = lo + n // 2
        run pf(f, lo, m - 1)
        run pf(f, m, hi)
    return
```

You also don't specify the cost of running threads, but your example
indicates it costs one unit of time so let's run with that. Also
assume that the cost of the loop body, your "Do-something" (here
represented as `f(lo)`) is also one. This gives us something like the
following schedule with `n = 5`.

| Time | T1 | T2 | T3 | T4 | T5 | T6 | T7 | T8 | T9 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | pf[1,5] |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 1 | run[1,2] | pf[1,2] |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 2 | run[3,5] | run[1,1] | pf[3,5] | pf[1,1] |  |  |  |  |  |
| 3 |  | run[2,2] | run[3,3] | f(1) | pf[2,2] | pf[3,3] |  |  |  |
| 4 |  |  | run[4,5] |  | f(2) | f(3) | pf[4,5] |  |  |
| 5 |  |  |  |  |  |  | run[4,4] | pf[4,4] |  |
| 6 |  |  |  |  |  |  | run[5,5] | f(4) | pf[5,5] |
| 7 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | f(5) |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

The numbers in square brackets denote the values of the `lo` and `hi`
parameters and `T1` to `T6` denote the six threads launched. So at
time 0 the main thread (`T1`) enters the `pf` function and on time 1
and 2 it launches threads `T2` and `T3` to handle subranges [1,2] and
[3,5]. And so it continues. Here, I have only illustrated one loop,
because the table would become very wide if we also added the inner
loop. For `n=5` you would need to start at least 4 + 3+ 2 + 1 = 10
threads.